# SAS CATX with empty delimiter

Tags: sas

I want to concatenate without any spaces using the `CATX` function but I seem to always have a space as a delimter.

```
Data test;
test=catx("","/\b","LTD","\b/");
run;


Proc print;
run;
```

I end up with `\b LTD \b` if I use a different seperator for e.g. `A` I get the expected output of `\bALTDA\b`

I know I could use ``` "/\b"||trim("LTD")||/\b"`` to replicate the function but I was wondering how to it with the ``` catx` function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I always end up back here when having concatenation issues:
https://www.sascrunch.com/cat-catt-cats-catx-functions.html

I think you'll want to use cats(), as this will strip any leading and trailing spaces you have.

Answer (score 0):

Why not simply use the CAT Function?

```
Data test;
test=cat("/\b","LTD","\b/");
run;

Proc print;
run;
```

Comment: The code above is a simplication of the code i am using. It would be "cleaner" if i could use a function that can concatenate and trim at the same time.